# Should all dependencies be created at the layer below?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, domain-driven-design, domain-model

Say I have the following classes:

```
ServiceLayer.Service > BusinessLayer.BusinessClass1 > BusinessLayer.BusinessClass2> BusinessLayer.BusinessClass3.
```

In the scenario above; Service calls BusinessClass1, which calls BusinessClass2, which calls BusinessClass3.

Say each of the classes have a dependency that needs to be injected:

IDependancy1 is required by BusinessClass1 and should be constructor injected; IDependancy2 is required by BusinessClass2 and should be constructor injected etc.

Should all of the dependencies be created by the service layer or should the business layer class create the dependencies that the class they call uses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have dependencies declared and managed at the lowest point necessary.  I would also strive not to have such a long chain of responsibility if at all possible.

- When building, `ServiceLayer.Service` only cares about it's interaction with `BusinessLayer.BusinessClass1` and nothing else.  It shouldn't be `ServiceLayer.Service`'s responsibility to know anything about the internals of the `BusinessLayer.BusinessClass1`.
- When testing, you mock out `BusinessLayer.BusinessClass1` so that you can test that it was called in the manner you expected.  The whole chain is irrelevant.
- Follow the same trend for constructing and testing each link so that they remain independent.

When you do this, you can refactor `BusinessLayer.BusinessClass1` so that it no longer needs the other dependencies and `ServiceLayer.Service` will still work just fine.

If you use one of the many dependency injection frameworks out there to handle this for you, that's essentially what they are doing.  It will be the least brittle way to handle the problem.

Comment: Thanks.  I believe you are saying it is acceptable (and advisable) for a Business class to create an instance of another business class .  Is that right?

Comment: Essentially.  Or let the DI framework (like Ninject) handle it for you.

Answer (score 6):

> Should all of the dependencies be created by the service layer or should the business layer class create the dependencies that the class they call uses?

Ideally, all of your dependencies are created (in order) by [the composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).

Think of your dependencies as a graph; there should be no cycles (no circular) dependencies).  So the root can just start by building leaves, and then the objects that depend on the leaves, and so on until the entire service/application has been assembled.

One of the benefits of constructor injection is that each object is documenting explicitly the dependencies that need to be satisfied.

Comment: Look It also from the SRP point of view. If Service layer is aware of so low level implementation details of the Business layer, probably It's gathering too much knowledge about the implementation so it potentially breaks all the underlying abstractions from the servíce up to the business. We could refer also to the Law of Demeter. Our service layer would have so many *friends* to be able to speak with. So looking these both violations is easy to agree with @VoiceOfUnreason.